# Programming game in flash/as3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, scripting-language

I have a bunch of ideas for different games (for programmers) where you have to write some program to complete the puzzle; The language shouldn't be too complicated and I even started thinking about a graphical language like Scratch (http://scratch.mit.edu/).

Anyway, I wanted to explore what people had done already porting various scripting languages to as3; BASIC would be a good start, or some tinyc derivative, however - I'm not sure how to search for this using google; the words "flash" and "as3" just dilute the resulsts and trying to use another programming language in there was well just breaks the resulsts even further - so I was hoping somebody has looked into this already and has further details on their experience.

The games essentialy control a vehicle of sorts, using turn and move commands and reading sensors to determine what to do; etc etc.

Many thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) supports ActionScript 3 these days, so you can implement your own custom language in a matter of hours.

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 implementations of Lua in actionscript on this page:
http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaImplementations

Lua is used in World of Warcraft. I recon people who make WoW addons in Lua would also like playing a programming game :)